# Django: Handing POST and GET requests in view

Tags: django, post, get, django-views

I have a django app that processes both POST and GET requests.

What is "the best" way to design the view? Should I have separate methods to handle each type of request? Or should I just use one method? Or should the methods be dependent on the functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: POST and GET are processed in controllers, not the view. It is up to you to decide how to structure your view. Keep that logic separate from your controller logic though

Comment: @thedarklord47 Django uses a slightly odd definition of view (and calls itself a model-template-view framework), so GET/POST are processed in the view.

Comment: It's a personal preference. You can have single function, separate functions, for use a CBV - `APIView`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`function based views`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/) or [`Class based views`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/):

In the first case:

```
# function based views

def my_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Handle post method
    else:  # request.method == 'GET'
        # Handle get method
```

In the second case:

```
# Class based views

class MyView(View):  # Use the view that fix your needs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Handle get method
        return HttpResponse()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Handle post method
        return HttpResponse()
```